# SQL where, case between or equal date vs datetime

Tags: sql, date, datetime, case

I'm trying to figure out if there are too many moving pieces in this query or not. I need check that if a date is on a Friday, the corresponding value is from the following Monday. Any other day, it is the next day. I can get the 'next day' part to work with no problems, but the Friday to Monday piece fails. Making it a little tougher is that a.Change_Date is in Date format and the b.Load_Date is in DateTime format.

```
SELECT *
  FROM a, b
  where a.account_number = b.account_Number
  and a.Change_date 
  case  when datepart(dw, a.Change_date) = 5
            then BETWEEN (CAST(DATEADD(dd, -4, b.Load_Date) AS DATE)) AND (CAST(DATEADD(dd, -3, b.Load_Date) AS DATE))
        else
            = CAST(b.Load_Date) AS DATE) and CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, b.Load_Date) AS DATE)
    end
  and a.Account_Number in 
(XXXXX.....)
```

Any thoughts on how to make this happen appreciated. This should return all rows where the account_numbers exist in the last and statement. I've looked at this too long today and not made enough progress.

Comment: Have you noticed the equal sign after else clause? I think you may replace it with a opening parenthesis.

Comment: The datatype differences aren't really your problem.  Your just overthinking the problem.  The dw value for Friday=6 so when the datepart(dw,DATE)=6 add 3 to the date.  Otherwise just add one to the date.  See the answer below.  It's pretty simple when you step back from it for a minute.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I missed some information. I'm on SQL Server 2012. That probably would have helped a little.
Thanks Steve, I was looking at this all wrong. It was much simpler than I was making it. I used the following where clause:

    where a.account_number = b.account_Number
    and CAST(a.Change_date AS DATE) =
    case 
 when datepart(dw, a.Change_date) = 6
  then CAST(DATEADD(dd, -3, b.Load_Date) AS DATE)
 else
  CAST(DATEADD(dd, -1, b.Load_Date) AS DATE)
 end

Thanks for being a sounding board. Lots of great info on this site. Good to see forums like this are still as alive as ever!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full schema, but here is a quick example with some local variables.

```
declare @somedate datetime = '2016-04-15 15:17:00.497'--getdate()
declare @nextDate datetime

select @nextDate = case when datepart(dw,@somedate)=6 then @somedate+3 else @somedate+1 end 

select @nextDate NextDate
```